# Possible to use iMac Pro as a monitor for a variety of devices?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac-pro

I am interested to know if it possible to use normally an iMac Pro and then switch on the fly between several different devices connected to it (through a dock for example).

I am mostly interested in connecting:

- MacBook Pro (late 2014 model)
- MacBook Pro (latest model)
- Mac Pro
- Windows Desktop

What are the necessary dongles, devices, equipment required?

What is your experience with that setup (bugs and problems)?

This question maybe sound like a duplicate but I am asking specifically for the iMacPro (2018 model) and not just an iMac.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the iMac pro as monitor for other devices natively.

However there are ways that may achieve what you need.

1. Screen sharing. Macos has build in screen sharing capability. And Microsoft has free Remote Desktop in the app store.
2. Synergy keyboard and mouse sharing software from [Symless](https://symless.com/synergy). It works across Windows, MacOS and Linux. The core is free and open source, but you will have to paid if you want the GUI.